# Transform a dropdown from Material UI to Bootstrap

Tags: javascript, reactjs, twitter-bootstrap, drop-down-menu, material-ui

I need to do this transformation because the dropdown from Material UI looks bad.

Beside of that, the code is working fine. It is a dropdown with multiple choices, it loads a list of strings and their corresponding images and when they are filtered by that category/categories are shown in the table.

This is the working code with Material UI:

```
import {
  Select,
  MenuItem,
  FormControl,
  InputLabel,
} from '@material-ui/core';

const platforms = ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd'];


    <FormControl className='searchPlatform'>
      <InputLabel id='platforLabel'>Platform</InputLabel>
      <Select
        labelId='platforLabel'
        id='platforLabel'
        value={this.props.platformFilter}
        renderValue={this.getSelectedPlatformFilter}
        onChange={this.handleChangePlatform}
        multiple
      >
        {platforms.map((platform) => (
          <MenuItem key={platform} value={platform}>
            <div>
              <img
                src={this.showicon(platform)}
                alt=''
                height={17}
                width={17}
              />
              {platform}
            </div>
          </MenuItem>
        ))}
      </Select>
    </FormControl>
```

And the next one is what I've tried with Bootstrap. I don't know how to trigger the dropdown on `onChange`. I've tried to put `onClick` on `Dropdown.Item` in order to call the same trigger as in `onChange` from `Dropdown.Menu`

```
import { Dropdown } from 'react-bootstrap';

<Dropdown>
          <Dropdown.Toggle variant='success' id='dropdown-basic'>
            Dropdown Button
          </Dropdown.Toggle>
          <Dropdown.Menu
            value={this.props.platformFilter}
            renderValue={this.getSelectedPlatformFilter}
            onChange={this.handleChangePlatform}
          >
            {platforms.map((platform) => (
              <Dropdown.Item
                eventKey={platform}
                value={platform}
                onClick={this.handleChangePlatform}
              >
                <div>
                  <img
                    src={this.showicon(platform)}
                    alt=''
                    height={17}
                    width={17}
                  />
                  {platform}
                </div>
              </Dropdown.Item>
            ))}
          </Dropdown.Menu>
        </Dropdown>
```

Comment: Did my answer help @Leo?

Answer (score 1):

Try `onSelect` prop on `<Dropdown>` component, as it's a callback fired when a menu item is selected.

```js
(eventKey: any, event: Object) => any
```

It would be something like:

```js
<Dropdown onSelect={handleChangePlatform}>
          <Dropdown.Toggle variant='success' id='dropdown-basic'>
            Dropdown Button
          </Dropdown.Toggle>
          <Dropdown.Menu>
          // ... rest of code
          </Dropdown.Menu>
</Dropdown>
```